# What should be given to the render method of a ClearableFileInput?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a custom MultiWidget containing a ClearableFileInput widget. This MultiWidget manipulates small lists of strings (the list is encoded as a string in the database). Each of these string corresponds to a filename.

In order to connect that nicely with a ClearableFileInput widget, I would like to know what type of element should be returned by the MultiWidget's "decompress()" method.

I assume each value of the list returned by the "decompress()" method is then passed as the parameter "value" in the corresponding Widget's "render()" method. But what should be the type of this parameter "value" in case of a ClearableFileInput widget?